# Math question from the GMATprep

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

If $xy=1$ what is the value of: $2^{(x+y)^2}/2^{(x-y)^2}$

```
A 1
B 2
C 4
D 16
E 19
```

$(x+y)^2/(x-y)^2$ because $2$ just cancels out from numerator and denominator, right?

Comment: No the 2 does not cancel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't as hard as you think.

```
xy = 1*1 or -1*-1

If xy = 1*1 then:

2^(x+y)^2/2^(x-y)^2 = (2^(2)^2)/(2^0^2) = 16/1 = 16

If xy = -1 *-1 then:

2^(x+y)^2/2^(x-y)^2 = (2^(-2)^2)/2^(-1 - (-1) )^2 = 16/1 = 16.
```

So, D is the answer. Let me know if you're confused

Comment: Great answer! But its takes time to understand, I need to think a little more... :)

Comment: If $xy=1$ then ($x=1$ and $y=1$) or ($x=-1$ and $y=-1$) ? You assume here that we're talking about integers...

Comment: If you're short on time, such questions can be answered with just looking at a one particular case (or two as in this answer). Since question implies that a single value is obtained whenever $xy=1$, you can plugin anything that works, e.g. $x=1$ or $y=1$, and assume that it remains the same for other cases. Use this at your own risk however.

Comment: It's nowhere stated that $x$ and $y$ are integer. Note that:

$$x = 100 \quad y = \frac 1{100}$$

would work.

Answer (score 8):

Using exponentiation rules, it can be simplified.

$$ \frac{2^{(x+y)^2}}{2^{(x-y)^2}} = 2^{(x+y)^² - (x-y)^2} = 2^{x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - (x^2 - 2xy + y^2)} = 2^{4xy} = \left(2^{4}\right)^{xy} = 16 $$